# pickling class method

Tags: python, methods, python-3.x, pickle

I have a class whose instances need to format output as instructed by the user. There's a default format, which can be overridden. I implemented it like this:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, params):
    # ...
    # by default printing all float values as percentages with 2 decimals
    self.format_functions = {float: lambda x : '{:.2%}'.format(x)}
  def __str__(self):
    # uses self.format_functions to format output
    # ...

a = A(params)
print(a) # uses default output formatting

# overriding default output formatting
# float printed as percentages 3 decimal digits; bool printed as Y / N
a.format_functions = {float : lambda x: '{:.3%}'.format(x),
                      bool : lambda x: 'Y' if x else 'N'}
print(a)
```

Is it ok? Let me know if there is a better way to design this.

Unfortunately, I need to pickle instances of this class. But only functions defined at the top level of the module can be pickled; `lambda` functions are unpicklable, so my `format_functions` instance attribute breaks the pickling.

I tried rewriting this to use a class method instead of lambda functions, but still no luck for the same reason:

```
class A:
  @classmethod
  def default_float_format(cls, x):
    return '{:.2%}'.format(x)
  def __init__(self, params):
    # ...
    # by default printing all float values as percentages with 2 decimals
    self.format_functions = {float: self.default_float_format}
  def __str__(self):
    # uses self.format_functions to format output
    # ...

a = A(params)
pickle.dump(a) # Can't pickle <class 'method'>: attribute lookup builtins.method failed
```

Note that pickling here doesn't work even if I don't override the defaults; just the fact that I assigned `self.format_functions = {float : self.default_float_format}` breaks it.

What to do? I'd rather not pollute the namespace and break encapsulation by defining `default_float_format` at the module level.

Incidentally, why in the world does `pickle` create this restriction? It certainly feels like a gratuitous and substantial pain to the end user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For pickling of class instances or functions (and therefore methods), Python's pickle depend that their name is available as global variables - the reference to the method in the dictionary points to a name that is not available in the global name space - which iis better said "module namespace" -

You could circunvent that by customizing the pickling of your class, by creating teh "__setstate__"  and "__getstate__" methods - but I think you be better, since the formatting function does not depend on any information of the object or of the class itself (and even if some formatting function does, you could pass that as parameters), and define a function outside of the class scope.

This does work (Python 3.2):

```
def default_float_format( x):
    return '{:.2%}'.format(x)

class A:

  def __init__(self, params):
    # ...
    # by default printing all float values as percentages with 2 decimals
    self.format_functions = {float: default_float_format}
  def __str__(self):
    # uses self.format_functions to format output
    pass

a = A(1)
pickle.dumps(a)
```

Comment: I don't mind that, but what if another class needs a different default? Then I'll have `default_float_format_for_class_A`, `default_float_format_for_class_B`, etc. at the module level. Aren't they better as class methods (or static methods)?  Also, if `pickle` can be made to work with class methods, why isn't it done in the standard `pickle` module? Is there some downside to this?

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `dill` module, either of your two approaches will just "work" **as is**.  `dill` can pickle `lambda` as well as instances of classes and also class methods.

*No need to pollute the namespace and break encapsulation, as you said you didn't want to do… but the other answer does*.

`dill` is basically ten years or so worth of finding the right `copy_reg` function that registers how to serialize the majority of objects in standard python.  Nothing special or tricky, it just takes time.  So why doesn't `pickle` do this for us?  Why does `pickle` have this restriction?

Well, if you look at the `pickle` docs, the answer is there:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled

> Basically: Functions and classes are pickled by reference.

This means `pickle` does not work on objects defined in `__main__`, and it also doesn't work on many *dynamically modified* objects.  `dill` registers `__main__` as a module, so it has a valid namespace.  `dill` also given you the option to not pickle by reference, so you can serialize *dynamically modified* objects… and class instances, class methods (bound and unbound), and so on.

Comment: Observation: you're missing a link to dill