# Issues while running pyspark UDF with AWS glue

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to call UDF in AWS glue job  but getting error . Code and error are given below

```
import sys,os
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import *
import boto3
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.context import SparkConf
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import array
from pyspark.sql.functions import sha2, concat_ws
from pyspark.sql.functions import  udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import StringType
import requests
import json



###############################

class JobBase(object):
    
    fair_scheduler_config_file= "fairscheduler.xml"
    rowAsDict={}
    listVendorDF=[]
    Oracle_Username=None
    Oracle_Password=None
    Oracle_jdbc_url=None
    futures=[]
    ataccama_url=None
    #all spark configuations can be passed in object in s3 bucket 
    ataccama_cleanse_udf=udf(lambda x:self.__cleanse_dnb_attribute(x),StringType() )
    
    
    
    def __cleanse_dnb_attribute(v_dnb_attr):
        payload = '{"in":{"src_org_name":"' + v_dnb_attr +'","sco_in":0,"exp_in":""}}'
        r = requests.post(self.ataccama_url, data=payload)  # response
        r.raise_for_status()
        if r is not None:
            r2 = json.loads(r.text)
            if r2['out'] is not None:
                r3 = r2['out']['cio_org_name'].replace(' ', '')
                return r3
            else:
                ''
        else:
            ''

  

    def __start_spark_glue_context(self):
        conf = SparkConf().setAppName("python_thread").set('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR').set("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", self.fair_scheduler_config_file)
        self.sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
        self.glueContext = GlueContext(self.sc)
        self.spark = self.glueContext.spark_session
        
        
        
    def __spark_read_from_table(self,table_name):
        #return self.spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", self.Oracle_jdbc_url).option("dbtable", table_name).option("user", self.Oracle_Username).option("password", self.Oracle_Password).option("numPartitions",2).load()
        return self.glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", self.Oracle_jdbc_url).option("dbtable", table_name).option("user", self.Oracle_Username).option("password", self.Oracle_Password).option("numPartitions",2)\
        .option("lowerBound", 1)\
        .option("upperBound",10000)\
        .option("partitionColumn", "ORG_CODE").load()
        # Connecting to the source
       #d f = glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", jdbc_driver_name).option("url", db_url).option("dbtable", table_name).option("user", db_username).option("password", db_password).load()
        
            
    def execute(self):
        self.__start_spark_glue_context()
        
        args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME','ataccma-cleanse-url'])
        self.ataccama_url=args['ataccma_cleanse_url']
        self.logger = self.glueContext.get_logger()
        self.logger.info("Starting Glue Threading job ")
        # ####connect to EDQDB  edqdb-dev
        client = boto3.client('glue', region_name='XXXXXXXXXX')
        response = client.get_connection(Name='XXXXXXXX')
        connection_properties = response['Connection']['ConnectionProperties']
        URL = connection_properties['JDBC_CONNECTION_URL']
        url_list = URL.split("/")
        host = "{}".format(url_list[-2][:-5])
        new_host=host.split('@',1)[1]
        port = url_list[-2][-4:]
        database = "{}".format(url_list[-1])
        self.Oracle_Username = "{}".format(connection_properties['USERNAME'])
        self.Oracle_Password = "{}".format(connection_properties['PASSWORD'])
        #no. jobs which can run in parallel 
        spark_pool_configuration=3
        print("Host:",host)
        print("New Host:",new_host)
        print("Port:",port)
        print("Database:",database)
        self.Oracle_jdbc_url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//"+new_host+":"+port+"/"+database
        print("Oracle_jdbc_url:",self.Oracle_jdbc_url)

        
        ############testing to check hash ############################
        source_df =self.spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", self.Oracle_jdbc_url).option("dbtable", "(select ENTERPRISE_NUM,ENTERPRISE_NAME,DNB_BUS_NM_TXT,DNB_SITE_BUS_STR_TXT  from xxgmdmadm.mdm_firmographic_data_v2 where ORG_ACCT_ID in (11758718960,11758836692)) ").option("user", self.Oracle_Username).option("password", self.Oracle_Password).load()
        source_df.show(truncate=False)
        
        # columnarray = array(self.arr_list)
        # print(columnarray)
        # source_df.withColumn("row_sha2", sha2(concat_ws("||", columnarray), 256)).show(truncate=False)
        
         ############testing to check hash finished  ############################
         
         
         ################test to check if we are getting variable name ###############
        source_df=source_df.withColumn('DNB_BUS_NM_TXT_CLEANSED',self.ataccama_cleanse_udf( source_df['DNB_BUS_NM_TXT'])).show(truncate=False)


def main():
    job = JobBase()
    job.execute() 
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

error I am getting

> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <**main**.JobBase
> object at 0x7f4a77382390> of type <class '**main**.JobBase'>. For
> column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map'
> function.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved . I did following changes referring mentioned link
[Pyspark User-Defined_functions inside of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58416527/pyspark-user-defined-functions-inside-of-a-class)

```
class JobBase(object):
   
   #all udf has to be initialised as first step 
   def __init__(self):
       print("Inside the constructor of Class phases ")
       self.ataccama_cleanse_udf=udf(JobBase.cleanse_dnb_attribute,StringType() )

@staticmethod
   def cleanse_dnb_attribute(v_dnb_attr):


source_df=source_df.withColumn('DNB_BUS_NM_TXT_CLEANSED',self.ataccama_cleanse_udf( source_df['DNB_BUS_NM_TXT'])).show(truncate=False)
```